# How do I connect multiple computers to a socket server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, server

I am making a small python based chat application using the socket and threading packages.

One part of the application is a server, which works as intended.
The other part is the client side application, which also pretty much works fine.
The client enters the desired host IP and Port the host has opened for the server. I can connect a local client to a server I have running (a client and server on the same computer), however when I try to connect to a server with another computer running a client, I get a TimeoutError;

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Client.py", line 46, in connect
    client_socket.connect(ADDR)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Not sure why this happens. I thought the port might be blocked but I haven't found any examples of anyone else with this particular problem after google searching.

I have uploaded both the server and client side applications to a github repository; https://github.com/gamer1117/chatapplication

All help is appreciated.

Comment: If everything works fine on the same PC, in most cases, connectivity issues are caused by either an invalid IP address or a blocked port. Are you attempting a LAN connection?

Comment: @Axe319 Both computers are connected to the same router, so I believe so (I would also like this to work over multiple routers all over the world). The IP address I am using for the second computer is the one I get from 'hostIP = gethostbyname(hostName)', performed by the server,  so the IP address is fine. The port I opened is 33000, because it's far away from all the important ones. I haven't done any port forwarding.

Comment: I just connected fine on my LAN with it. The one you are getting with `gethostbyname()` is not necessarily the correct one. For instance, the IP `gethostbyname()` is showing for me is 192.168.1.137, however I'm connected through a virtual switch using 192.168.1.97 so that's the one I actually connect on via the client.

Comment: @Axe319 I'm pretty sure It's the right IP, because I check netstat and it shows the local IP as the same one the server displays, and when I use a different IP I get a different error message that says "The target machine actively refused a connection". This made me think that the problem was a blocked port or something.

Comment: That is most likely your firewall blocking it.